# Include path error in conan cmake configuration

Tags: cmake, conan

conanfile.txt //i am using local repo

```
[requires]
libxml2/2.9.0@conan/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
 project(testlibxml)

 include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
 conan_basic_setup()

 add_executable(test_xml_lib test_xml.cpp)
```

test_xml.cpp

```
 #include <libxml/xlink.h>

 int main(){

     return 0;
 }
```

I expect includes to be resolved properly, but i am getting below error

```
error: libxml/xlink.h: No such file or directory.
```

It works if i add below line in CmakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}/libxml2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where are you getting that version of the libxml2 package, because it is not in conan-center:

```
$ conan search libxml* -r=conan-center
Existing package recipes:

libxml2/2.9.3@bincrafters/stable
libxml2/2.9.8@bincrafters/stable
```

So what you are using might be an old, stale, or broken version from somewhere else. Changing your conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
libxml2/2.9.8@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

And I have checked it works (at least in Windows)

Comment: Thanks @drodri I am using linux and its my local instance of artifactory. may i see your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I am  using your CMakeLists.txt, copied from above, exactly. Same with the .cpp file. I only changed the requires version in conanfile.txt. So the problem might not be in the consumption of the package, but in your libxml package itself. You might check the local cache, it is easy to navigate, you will learn how the package is stored, what is being copied and where. Also, using Github issues in the conan github repo is possible, and more suitable for discussion and help.